# RDLC Lookup not working

Tags: winforms, rdlc, reportviewer

I have a `Table` that has a set of data with integers that mark where to look in another `dataset` for their string description. I have tried to use:

```
=LOOKUP(
        CINT(Fields!LTC_Leak.Value),
        CINT(Fields!LTC_Leak.Value),
        Fields!LTC_LeakDesc.Value,
        "LeakCheckTypes"
        )
```

This should be using the integer field `LTC_Leak` from the details `dataset` the table is scoped too and lookup the row in the `"LeakCheckTypes"` `dataset` for it's description but i keep getting the error:

```
The Value expression for the text box 'LeakCheckType' refers to the field 'LTC_LeakDesc'. Report item expressions can only refer to fields within the current dataset scope or, if inside an aggregate, the specified dataset scope.
```

I have used the debugger to check and all the `datasets` are present, named properly, and have all the proper data. Anyone have an idea what I am doing wrong here?

Adding xml from the datasetmodel I used (shortened to the affected tables)

```
    <xs:element name="Details" msprop:Generator_TableClassName="DetailsDataTable" msprop:Generator_TableVarName="tableDetails" msprop:Generator_RowChangedName="DetailsRowChanged" msprop:Generator_TablePropName="Details" msprop:Generator_RowDeletingName="DetailsRowDeleting" msprop:Generator_RowChangingName="DetailsRowChanging" msprop:Generator_RowEvHandlerName="DetailsRowChangeEventHandler" msprop:Generator_RowDeletedName="DetailsRowDeleted" msprop:Generator_RowClassName="DetailsRow" msprop:Generator_UserTableName="Details" msprop:Generator_RowEvArgName="DetailsRowChangeEvent">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="Row" msprop:Generator_ColumnVarNameInTable="columnRow" msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInRow="Row" msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInTable="RowColumn" msprop:Generator_UserColumnName="Row" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
          <xs:element name="OPRID" msprop:Generator_ColumnVarNameInTable="columnOPRID" msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInRow="OPRID" msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInTable="OPRIDColumn" msprop:Generator_UserColumnName="OPRID" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
          <xs:element name="NAME" msprop:Generator_ColumnVarNameInTable="columnNAME" msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInRow="NAME" msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInTable="NAMEColumn" msprop:Generator_UserColumnName="NAME" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
          <xs:element name="LTC_Cure" msprop:Generator_ColumnVarNameInTable="columnLTC_Cure" msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInRow="LTC_Cure" msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInTable="LTC_CureColumn" msprop:Generator_UserColumnName="LTC_Cure" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
          <xs:element name="LTC_Leak" msprop:Generator_ColumnVarNameInTable="columnLTC_Leak" msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInRow="LTC_Leak" msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInTable="LTC_LeakColumn" msprop:Generator_UserColumnName="LTC_Leak" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
          <xs:element name="LTC_VacuumCheck" msprop:Generator_ColumnVarNameInTable="columnLTC_VacuumCheck" msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInRow="LTC_VacuumCheck" msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInTable="LTC_VacuumCheckColumn" msprop:Generator_UserColumnName="LTC_VacuumCheck" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
          <xs:element name="LTC_VacuumInterval" msprop:Generator_ColumnVarNameInTable="columnLTC_VacuumInterval" msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInRow="LTC_VacuumInterval" msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInTable="LTC_VacuumIntervalColumn" msprop:Generator_UserColumnName="LTC_VacuumInterval" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
          <xs:element name="LTC_VacuumCheckType" msprop:Generator_ColumnVarNameInTable="columnLTC_VacuumCheckType" msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInRow="LTC_VacuumCheckType" msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInTable="LTC_VacuumCheckTypeColumn" msprop:Generator_UserColumnName="LTC_VacuumCheckType" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="LeakCheckTypes" msprop:Generator_TableClassName="LeakCheckTypesDataTable" msprop:Generator_TableVarName="tableLeakCheckTypes" msprop:Generator_TablePropName="LeakCheckTypes" msprop:Generator_RowDeletingName="LeakCheckTypesRowDeleting" msprop:Generator_RowChangingName="LeakCheckTypesRowChanging" msprop:Generator_RowEvHandlerName="LeakCheckTypesRowChangeEventHandler" msprop:Generator_RowDeletedName="LeakCheckTypesRowDeleted" msprop:Generator_UserTableName="LeakCheckTypes" msprop:Generator_RowChangedName="LeakCheckTypesRowChanged" msprop:Generator_RowEvArgName="LeakCheckTypesRowChangeEvent" msprop:Generator_RowClassName="LeakCheckTypesRow">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="LTC_Leak" msprop:Generator_ColumnVarNameInTable="columnLTC_Leak" msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInRow="LTC_Leak" msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInTable="LTC_LeakColumn" msprop:Generator_UserColumnName="LTC_Leak" type="xs:int" />
          <xs:element name="LTC_LeakDesc" msprop:Generator_ColumnVarNameInTable="columnLTC_LeakDesc" msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInRow="LTC_LeakDesc" msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInTable="LTC_LeakDescColumn" msprop:Generator_UserColumnName="LTC_LeakDesc">
            <xs:simpleType>
              <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xs:maxLength value="20" />
              </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
          </xs:element>
          <xs:element name="Leak_Tolerance" msprop:Generator_ColumnVarNameInTable="columnLeak_Tolerance" msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInRow="Leak_Tolerance" msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInTable="Leak_ToleranceColumn" msprop:Generator_UserColumnName="Leak_Tolerance" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0" />
          <xs:element name="LC_Length" msprop:Generator_ColumnVarNameInTable="columnLC_Length" msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInRow="LC_Length" msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInTable="LC_LengthColumn" msprop:Generator_UserColumnName="LC_Length" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
          <xs:element name="VTA" msprop:Generator_ColumnVarNameInTable="columnVTA" msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInRow="VTA" msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInTable="VTAColumn" msprop:Generator_UserColumnName="VTA" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="0" />
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
```

XML from the RDLC file:

```
<DataSet Name="LeakCheckTypes">
  <Query>
    <DataSourceName>OprData</DataSourceName>
    <CommandText>/* Local Query */</CommandText>
  </Query>
  <Fields>
    <Field Name="LTC_Leak">
      <DataField>LTC_Leak</DataField>
      <rd:TypeName>System.Int32</rd:TypeName>
    </Field>
    <Field Name="LTC_LeakDesc">
      <DataField>LTC_LeakDesc</DataField>
      <rd:TypeName>System.String</rd:TypeName>
    </Field>
    <Field Name="Leak_Tolerance">
      <DataField>Leak_Tolerance</DataField>
      <rd:TypeName>System.Decimal</rd:TypeName>
    </Field>
    <Field Name="LC_Length">
      <DataField>LC_Length</DataField>
      <rd:TypeName>System.Int32</rd:TypeName>
    </Field>
    <Field Name="VTA">
      <DataField>VTA</DataField>
      <rd:TypeName>System.Boolean</rd:TypeName>
    </Field>
  </Fields>
  <rd:DataSetInfo>
    <rd:DataSetName>OprData</rd:DataSetName>
    <rd:SchemaPath>C:\Users\aridder\Desktop\AC Recipe Builder\AC Recipe Builder\OprReports\OprData.xsd</rd:SchemaPath>
    <rd:TableName>LeakCheckTypes</rd:TableName>
    <rd:TableAdapterFillMethod>Fill</rd:TableAdapterFillMethod>
    <rd:TableAdapterGetDataMethod>GetData</rd:TableAdapterGetDataMethod>
    <rd:TableAdapterName>LeakCheckTypesTableAdapter</rd:TableAdapterName>
  </rd:DataSetInfo>
</DataSet>

<DataSet Name="Details">
  <Query>
    <DataSourceName>OprData</DataSourceName>
    <CommandText>/* Local Query */</CommandText>
  </Query>
  <Fields>
    <Field Name="Row">
      <DataField>Row</DataField>
      <rd:TypeName>System.String</rd:TypeName>
    </Field>
    <Field Name="OPRID">
      <DataField>OPRID</DataField>
      <rd:TypeName>System.String</rd:TypeName>
    </Field>
    <Field Name="NAME">
      <DataField>NAME</DataField>
      <rd:TypeName>System.String</rd:TypeName>
    </Field>
    <Field Name="LTC_Cure">
      <DataField>LTC_Cure</DataField>
      <rd:TypeName>System.String</rd:TypeName>
    </Field>
    <Field Name="LTC_Leak">
      <DataField>LTC_Leak</DataField>
      <rd:TypeName>System.String</rd:TypeName>
    </Field>
    <Field Name="LTC_VacuumCheck">
      <DataField>LTC_VacuumCheck</DataField>
      <rd:TypeName>System.String</rd:TypeName>
    </Field>
    <Field Name="LTC_VacuumInterval">
      <DataField>LTC_VacuumInterval</DataField>
      <rd:TypeName>System.String</rd:TypeName>
    </Field>
    <Field Name="LTC_VacuumCheckType">
      <DataField>LTC_VacuumCheckType</DataField>
      <rd:TypeName>System.String</rd:TypeName>
    </Field>
  </Fields>
  <rd:DataSetInfo>
    <rd:DataSetName>OprData</rd:DataSetName>
    <rd:SchemaPath>C:\Users\aridder\Desktop\AC Recipe Builder\AC Recipe Builder\OprReports\OprData.xsd</rd:SchemaPath>
    <rd:TableName>Details</rd:TableName>
    <rd:TableAdapterFillMethod />
    <rd:TableAdapterGetDataMethod />
    <rd:TableAdapterName />
  </rd:DataSetInfo>
</DataSet>
```

Comment: note: I have also tried not using CINT() on the fields and it gives the same error

Comment: The error makes me think that the field "LTC_LeakDesc" is not present in second dataset ("LeakCheckTypes"). Check your dataset definition (xml) and underlying query.

Comment: That's the odd thing is I checked with the debugger to make sure the columns and dataset names were all correct and had data. From my research before posting this question it appears to be something that shouldn't happen but I'm at a loss as to what is causing it since all the names are proper. I even tried deleting and remaking the datasets and how they are used within the whole app and nothing fixed the error.

Comment: Can you add XML portion with definitions of datasources  for your report to your question?

Comment: Are you able to convert the LTC_Leak field in the Details dataset to an INT in the database and trying with that. It could be the fact it's a string that's causing the reporting engine problems.

Comment: Doesn't `CINT()` do that? Or are you meaning convert the at the `dataset` itself?